# Increment value upto missing consicutive numbers

Tags: mysql, random, increment

I have a table with a field have values 1,2,3,5,6,....
My problem is,When i try to insert "2" current 2,3 are incremented with 1 and 5,6 remains unchanged(because 4 is not exist),Then in the place of 2 new value needs to be inserted.
I try update query with

```
    Update table set v1=v1+1 where v1>=newvalue
```

before insert a new value.But 5,6 also incremented with 1.I dont know how to do this.Does anyone know how to handle this ,Please help me.I have large amount of data,so not possible to make loop for update each value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.v1 + 1 AS gap
FROM `table` AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN `table` AS t2 ON t2.v1 = t1.v1 + 1
WHERE t2.v1 IS NULL AND t1.v1 >= :newvalue
ORDER BY t1.v1 ASC
LIMIT 1
```

This query gives the upper bound for updating `v1` when inserting `:newvalue`.

Comment: can you suggest a query for updating values that already being exist?I mean,If i change value "5" to "3" then 3 to 4 automaticaly change and 6 to 5 ,7 to 6 etc